# Український відповідник lifehack?

Tags: переклад, from-english, запозичені-слова, неологізми

Стаття у Вікіпедії [Лайфхак (Лайфга́к)](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9B%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%84%D1%85%D0%B0%D0%BA) зазначає, що

> Українські еквіваленти цього слова — «**кмітливість**», «**рецепт**»,
>   «**знахідка**».

Хоча розділ "Посилання" цієї ж статті свідчить, що переважно вживається звичайна транслітерація.

Про це ж свідчить і [Google пошук](https://www.google.com.ua/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=lifehack&start=10&*). Почасти використовується навіть в оригінальному англійському написанні.

Онлайн [Словник іншомовних слів](http://www.jnsm.com.ua/cgi-bin/u/book/sis.pl?Article=10723&action=show) містить таку статтю:

> **Лайфхак**
>
> англ. life hack - зріз (злам) життя коротка *`корисна порада`*, що дозволяє
>   з найменшими зусиллями вирішити життєве або побутове завдання; *`рецепт`*,
>   *`хитрість`*.

Народний [Словотвір](http://slovotvir.org.ua/words/laifkhak) пропонує все якісь кострубаті варіанти.

Натрапила на електронну версію [Словника неологізмів. Інновації у словниковому складі англійської мови початку ХХІ століття](https://books.google.com.ua/books?id=f1v9CQAAQBAJ&printsec=frontcover&hl=uk#v=onepage&q&f=false), але доступний тільки попередній перегляд (97 сторінок із 359), що закінчується словом *blooding*.

**Тож чи є якийсь варіант, зафіксований хоча б у одному із сучасних виданих словників?**

**UPD**

Що ж, більшість відповідей і коментарів свідчить, що словники ще не додали бодай якогось із варіантів, що зустрічаються.

У мене власних є два, але обидва навіть для мене далекі від ідеалу.

1. **Зметиківка** - притягнуте за вуха від *зметикувати*. Недоліки: Кострубате за звучанням, як і *лазівка*. Не очевидний зв'язок із *lifehack*.
2. **Мудринка** - новотвір від *мудрість+хитринка* (навіяно *хитринкою* від @Андрій Бандура). Недоліки: Етимологія зрозуміла, напевне, лиш автору.

Слушне також зауваження @Oleg, що при виборі не слід забувати про зв'язок з відповідниками *лайфгакер*, *лайфгакінг*.

Comment: А чим *«хитрик»* зі «Словотвору» не сподобався? Та і в газетах з давніх-давен були рубрики на зразок «маленькі хитрощі».

Comment: @bytebuster [СУМ](http://sum.in.ua/s/khytryk) каже, що це те ж саме, що й *хитрун*, тобто характеристика людини. Маємо новотвір-омонім.

Comment: На словотворі найбільш популярний переклад - "лазівка". http://sum.in.ua/s/lazivka. СУМ каже, що це:  "Хитрий, спритний прийом для виходу з певного, звичайно неприємного, скрутного становища." Перша частина речення відповідає сутності терміну якнайкраще, мені так здається.

Comment: @P.Vovk, хоч абсолютно суб'єктивно, але мені *лазівка* дуже схоже на кальку від російського *лазейка* (щось на кшталт *зупинівка*). Окрім того, друга частина визначення на СУМ зазначає, що зазвичай стосується неприємних, скрутних ситуацій. Що ж до лайфхаку, то не завжди така конотація. Власне, і *маленькі хитрощі*, як зазначив bytebuster, непоганий варіант, але з огляду на сучасні реалії, як і *господарочці на замітку* тощо, не охоплює найширшого спектру контекстів, у якому вживається lifehack. А ще ж хотілося, щоб було одним словом, а не виразом. Як погана свекруха: "Не знаю як, та не так":)

Comment: Не схоже що "Словник неологізмів" може допомогти - він дає тільки означення, але не переклади. Гугл дозволяє шукати в книзі, тільки він не знаходить ані hack, ані lifehack, ані life-hack.

Comment: @Artemix, я теж про це подумала, бо якийсь гібридний словник: нібито й двомовний, а нібито й тлумачний. Проте, там через крапку з комою можуть бути додані варіанти. Непогано було б подивитися, що там пропонують.

Comment: Моя прабабуся, хоч і по маминій лінії, а все про мого тата казала "от же метикуватий" за його вміння знаходити нестандартні рішення з будь-якого питання, і не тільки щодо господарства. І мене так і тягне утворити іменниковий відповідник до lifehack саме від [МЕТИКУВА́ТИЙ](http://sum.in.ua/s/metykuvatyj), [МЕТИКО́ВАНИЙ](http://sum.in.ua/s/metykovanyj), та щось мені наразі не вдається "зметикувати" :)

Comment: @Artemix, може, й немає. Дякую за підказку.

Comment: Google Translate при перекладі на російську дає єдиний варіант «ухищрение», який у словниках на R2U має [ось такі відповідники](http://r2u.org.ua/s?w=ухищрение&scope=rus&dicts=all) — це Ви «метикуванням» нагадали.

Comment: @Sasha, так-так, щось близьке до *метикування*. Біда в тім, що *метикування* - це більше процес, недоконана дія, тоді як *lifehack* - це вже "оформлений" результат метикування, так би мовити. І от з цим проблема)

Comment: Я зхитрував і взяв слова з тексту вашого питання, де наголоси були. Є така інструкція: http://www.slovomania.ru/dnevnik/2007/08/11/how-to-use-stress-sign/ і є обговорення тут: http://russian.stackexchange.com/q/1690/551

Comment: Що ж, більшість відповідей і коментарів свідчить, що словники ще не додали бодай якогось із варіантів, що зустрічаються. У мене власних є два, але обидва навіть для мене далекі від ідеалу. 1. **Зметиківка** - притягнуте за вуха від *зметикувати*. Недоліки: Кострубате за звучанням, як і *лазівка*. Не очевидний зв'язок із lifehack. 2. **Мудринка** - новотвір від *мудрість+хитринка* - навіяно *хитринкою* від Андрій Бандура. Недоліки: Етимологія зрозуміла, напевне, лиш автору. Слушне також зауваження Oleg, що при виборі не слід забувати про зв'язок з відповідниками *лайфгакер*, *лайфгакінг*.

Comment: @OksanaGubrenko, 
Оксано, а чи потрібен нам цей термін з його сімейством (лайфгакер, лайфгакінг...)? Це ж не науковий термін. Гадаю, що може бути і **мудринка** і **мудрагелин(к)а** )))

Comment: @Oleg, не впевнена, що потрібен із сімейством, принаймні, наразі. Але є припущення, що згодом це питання виникне.

Answer (score 8):

Гадаю, краще підійде слово "**Лазівка**" у переносному значенні.

> ЛАЗІ́ВКА, и, жін.
>
> 1. Те саме, що лаз1
> 2. перен. Хитрий, спритний прийом для виходу з певного, звичайно неприємного, скрутного становища.

Як варіант, **викрутні**, але [СУМ зазначає](http://sum.in.ua/s/vykrutenj), що у значенні хитрощі, воно вживається у множині.

> Що може бути кращим, ніж невеличкі *викрутні*, які можуть трохи або
>   кардинально покращити ваше життя вже зараз?

Але, звісно, другим вашим питанням буде про відповідники до "лайфгакера", "лайфгакінг" тощо.

Щодо сучасних словників, здається мені, що ви не знайдете нічого подібного до "Lifehack (англ.) –» [потрібне слово] (укр.)"

Comment: Дякую за відповідь. Перший варіант (*лазівка*) зазначав P.Vovk у коментарі до запитання. Там же я висловила свою думку стосовно цього. А щодо *викрутні* не могли б ви дати, будь ласка, посилання на СУМ, бо я не знайшла такого слова там. Зауваження по сучасних словниках, напевне, слушне, цю думку висловлювали майже всі, хто долучився до коментування цього питання.

Comment: @OksanaGubrenko, коментарі не читав))
http://sum.in.ua/s/vykrutenj

Comment: коментарі все ж раджу читати)

Comment: Lifehack - це два слова. Для точнішого перекладу важливо також вказувати і значення другого слова Життя. Тобто лазівка в житті. Бо втрачаєте частину перекладу.

Answer (score 5):

> [ХИ́ТРІСТЬ](http://sum.in.ua/s/khytristj), рості, жін. Властивість за значенням хитрий
>
> …
>
> **Маленька хитрість** удалась: узявши лист та нагадавши про вечерю, мати одразу ж
>   вийшла з кімнати (Андрій Головко, II, 1957, 582).

Гугл за запитом [*невеличка хитрість*](https://www.google.com.ua/?gws_rd=ssl#q=%22%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%BA%D0%B0%20%D1%85%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%80%D1%96%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C%22&*) дає майже 1000 результатів, на [одна хитрість](https://www.google.com.ua/?gws_rd=ssl#q=%22%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%B0%20%D1%85%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%80%D1%96%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C%22&*) ще більше, при чому слово *хитрість* чи навіть ціле словосполучення майже в кожному випадку можна замінити на *лайфхак* без зміни змісту.

Comment: Що ж, зв'язок «невеличка хитрість» з «lifehack» у Вас не підтверджується виданими словниками (я так розумію, саме про це Oksana Gubrenko просила в останньому реченні). Тим не менше мені подобається Ваш варінт, я теж думав про схожий («Англійсько-*російський* сучасний словник» (2012) на academic.ru дає переклад «[маленькая хитрость](http://top_english.academic.ru/48093/lifehack)», і якби він був виданий, то це можна було б вважати доведенням — але невідомо, чи він колись видавався).

Comment: @Sasha, погоджуюсь, непоганий варіант, перегукується із запропонованим bytebuster. Мене дивує, що варіантів насправді не так вже й мало, але словники не дають єдиного якогось. А тим часом експансія запозичення все відчутніша.

Comment: В українській мові наявні суфікси для зменшення предмету, явища чи процесу, тому замість невеличка хитрість краще звучатиме ХИТРИНКА. Українські словники це слово містять. Щоправда в англо-українських не надибав на нього.

Comment: @АндрійБандура, СУМ подає тільки одне значення [ХИТРИ́НКА](http://sum.in.ua/s/khytrynka) - "деяка хитрість, кмітливість, лукавство в кого-небудь, у чиємусь характері". Тобто, це риса характеру людини. А це, погодьтесь, трошки інше, аніж lifehack.

Comment: @АндрійБандура, було б непогане слово для lifehack. Але Oksana Gubrenko права — окрім значення «риса характеру» інших застосувань я не знайшов.

Answer (score 2):

Я хотів додати, як коментар до мого допису вище про переклад lifehack як хитринка. Але відповідь вийшла надто велика,тому подаю як повну відповідь. Отож, якщо скористатися українським лінгвістичним порталом http://lcorp.ulif.org.ua/dictua/dictua.aspx і ввести у рядок пошуку слово хитринка та заглянути на вкладку синонімія, то цитую звідтіля усі синоніми: ХИ́ТРОЩІ мн. (неправдиві, нерідко обманні слова, вчинки, хитрий прийом чи задум для досягнення мети), ХИ́ТРІСТЬ, ЛУКА́ВСТВО, КРУТІ́ЙСТВО, ХИТРОМУ́ДРОЩІ мн., розм.; ХИТРИ́НКА розм., ЛУКА́ВИНКА розм. (деяка хитрість, кмітливість); МАНЕ́ВР, ВИ́КРУТ розм., ВИ́КРУТКА розм., ВИ́ВЕРТ розм., ВИ́КРУТНІ мн., розм., ШТУ́КА розм., ШТУ́ЧКА розм., ФО́КУС розм., ФІ́ҐЛІ-МІҐЛІ мн., розм. (окремий хитрий прийом, спритна дія); ЕКІВО́КИ (перев. словесні викрути, двозначні натяки).

Як бачите, тут не обмежується лише рисою характеру.

Comment: Спробую пояснити, що мене так непокоїть у *хитринці* і подібних варіантах. І сама *хитринка*, і *хитрощі*, і весь синонімічний ряд має певний негативний семантичний відтінок, як на мене. Це як товариш Бендер, який знав "чотириста *відносно чесних* способів". А lifehack все ж охоплює і чесні способи, "що дозволяють з найменшими зусиллями вирішити життєве або побутове завдання", тобто розумом, кмітливістю, винахідливістю, а не тільки хитрощами. Розумієте, про що я?

Comment: @OksanaGubrenko, можна заперечити, що більшість із нас не є носіями англійської і тому не бачать *негативних конотацій* у слові *"hack"*.

Comment: Мені спало на думку слово „кмітлинка“. Негативних відтінків воно не має. Щоправда, у словниках ніби теж відсутнє. Але  знайшов, на диво, розробку одного уроку в інтернеті. Ось відповідне речення „4 зупинка. Зупинка-кмітлинка. В усі часи гострий розум, кмітливість, винахідливість допомагали людям. Перевіримо наскільки кмітливі ви. “ А це саме посилання -
 http://slavbibl4.at.ua/publ/podorozh_do_krajini_chomuchljandiji/1-1-0-8

Comment: @bytebuster, можу тільки частково прийняти зауваження. Саме по собі hack може й має якісь негативні конотоації. Та я мала на увазі, що вкупі lifehack охоплює ширший спектр конотацій, в тому числі й позитивні, на відімну від слів синонімічного ряду до *хитрощі*. Чому я казала, що мені ваш варіант *маленькі хитрощі* подобається? Тому що *маленькі* ніби дещо пом'якшує негативну семантику. За браком однослівного варіанту наразі *маленькі хитрощі* мені найбільше до вподоби.

Comment: @АндрійБандура, *кмітлинка* цікавий варіант, але, як на мене, дещо дитячий, що потенційно звужує сферу його застосування. Можливо, це тільки моє враження.

Answer (score 1):

**Трюк/виверт** (при самостійному застосуванні)
**Порада** (у випадку поширення лайфхаку)

Оксфордський словник [називає](https://www.lexico.com/definition/lifehack) лайфхаком **стратегію** або **техніку**:

> A **strategy** or **technique** adopted in order to manage one's time and daily activities in a more efficient way.

Англійська [Вікіпедія](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Life_hack) говорить про **трюк** (**викрут**), **найкоротший шлях**, **навик** або **новітній метод** (що є синонімом **підходу**):

> Any **trick**, **shortcut**, **skill**, or **novelty method** that increases
> productivity and efficiency, in all walks of life.

СУМ визначає [трюк](http://sum.in.ua/s/trjuk) як *"спритну витівку, хитрий несподіваний прийом, виверт"*, що, на мій погляд, цілком співпадає з англійським значенням *лайфхак*.

Однак, якщо ми ділимось **вивертом** з кимось іншим, то це перетворюєтья на **пораду**. А англомовний ресурс **Lifehacker** можна порівняти з журналом **Порадницею**, суть якого - давати корисні поради.

Answer (score 0):

Найпопулярнішими варіантом на [Словотворі](https://slovotvir.org.ua/words/laifkhak) є:

[Лазівка](http://sum.in.ua/s/lazivka)

[Вікіпедія](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9B%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%84%D1%85%D0%B0%D0%BA) також пропонує відпвоідники:

> Українські еквіваленти цього слова — «кмітливість», «рецепт»,
>   «знахідка».

Гадаю, що деколи це слово можна замінити "життєвим [секретом](http://sum.in.ua/s/sekret)", наприклад: "Він знав один життєвий секрет, а тому зміг легко розпалити багаття".

А от "лайхакінг" можна вже перекласти як "спрощення життя", а от слово "хитрик" (або "хитрун") з того самого Словотвору використати для "лайфхакера", або ж навіть "[спритник](http://sum.in.ua/s/sprytnyk)" чи "[ловкач](http://sum.in.ua/s/lovkach)".

Answer (score 0):

А як щодо слова [ярміс](http://sum.in.ua/s/jarmis) як українського аналогу до лайфхак?

Comment: Ласкаво просимо до сайту Ukrainian Language.SE! Наші критерії якості дещо відрізняються від того, що можна побачити на мовних форумах і блоґах. Необґрунтовані відповіді базуються лише на думці їхнього автора і тому викликають хвилю диспутів і заперечень. А якісні відповіді ґрунтуються на якісних джерелах: словниках, поважних сайтах тощо. Ви завжди можете виправити відповідь, зробивши її більш аргументованою. Для цього натисніть [edit]. Сторінки [tour], [answer] а також [«Якими мають бути гарні відповіді»](http://meta.ukrainian.stackexchange.com/q/5/) підкажуть, як можна покращити ваш допис.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/3347)

Comment: Цікава ідея! А Ви могли б навести приклади з літератури або Інтернету, де це _ярміс_ ужито в значенні, на Ваш погляд якомога ближчому до _lifehack_?

Comment: Оригінальний варіант. Значення відображає суть. Утім, я, наприклад, не чула такого слова раніше. Та й у словнику позначка, що діалектизм. Сумніви щодо питомості. Що скажете стосовно ужитку в сучасному мовленні?

Comment: Цікавий варіант, теж не чув такого слова раніше. Можна оформити в хорошу відповідь.

Answer (score -2):

Я би запропонував слово **життєрада**, звучить доволі приємно і відразу зрозуміла суть

Comment: Наші критерії якості дещо відрізняються від того, що можна побачити на мовних форумах і блоґах. Необґрунтовані відповіді базуються лише на думці їхнього автора і тому викликають хвилю диспутів і заперечень. А якісні відповіді ґрунтуються на якісних джерелах: словниках, поважних сайтах тощо. Ви завжди можете виправити відповідь, зробивши її більш аргументованою. Для цього натисніть [edit]. Сторінки [tour], [answer] а також [«Якими мають бути гарні відповіді»](http://meta.ukrainian.stackexchange.com/q/5/) підкажуть, як можна покращити ваш допис.