# Наголос у слові "фазанів"

Tags: resource-request, наголос

І де взагалі можна подивитися наголоси по відмінках?

Comment: Вітаємо на сайті Ukrainian Language.SE! Будь ласка, почитайте про [наші критерії](http://meta.ukrainian.stackexchange.com/q/5/), за якими ми оцінюємо хороші питання. Це питання (у тій формі що воно наразі має) навряд чи стане багатьом у нагоді в майбутньому. Ви завжди можете виправити свій допис за допомогою посилання [edit].

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**фаза́н** – іменник чоловічого роду, істота

```
відмінок  | однина                | множина
------------------------------------------
називний  | фаза́н                 | фаза́ни
родовий   | фаза́на                | фаза́нів
давальний | фаза́нові, фаза́ну      | фаза́нам
знахідний | фаза́на                | фаза́ни, фаза́нів
орудний   | фаза́ном               | фаза́нами
місцевий  | на/у фаза́нові, фаза́ні | на/у фаза́нах
кличний   | фаза́не                | фаза́ни
```

Ось тут [словник УЛІФ](http://lcorp.ulif.org.ua/dictua/)

Comment: До речі, є можливість подавати прямі посилання на УЛІФ, а саме — [фазани](http://lcorp.ulif.org.ua/ElWelding/Home/ContactUs?lang=uk&ww=%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8). Зверніть увагу на шлях посилання. Оце я називаю [lifehack](http://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/q/1053/36)!

Comment: @NashBridges, дуже цікаво! Хоча є певні недоліки: (1) `ElWelding` в шляху посилання підказує, що воно працює через [словник електрозварювання](http://lcorp.ulif.org.ua/ElWelding) (і справді, той словник інформацію про словозміну надає з основного); (2) як би воно з часом не перестало працювати (адже це не основна фішка словника електрозварювання, з часом можуть змінити і всім посиланням кінець); (3) інформація показується не повна (наприклад, [тут](http://lcorp.ulif.org.ua/ElWelding/Home/ContactUs?lang=uk&ww=козак) немає поміток «(річка в Україні)» і «* жіночі прізвища…»).